# Could Romania have remained neutral in WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, europe, war, romania, invasion

Romania was neutral at the beginning of WWII, but then Marshall Antonescu (as he liked to be called) went to visit Hitler and then joined the war on the German side. Things have happened as they happened, but I wonder if Romania could have stayed neutral for the entire duration of WWII in any other circumstances? Some historians say that it was inevitable, because of two main reasons:

1. Resources (mainly petroleum) and
2. Geographical position.

Although somehow right, I fail to believe in these two parameters, and I think that there was lack of diplomacy and negotiation*. Can this be right? Could they have negotiated their neutrality?

Sweden had resources and it was close to Russia too, and yet, they stayed neutral. Denmark was a strategic point because of its Atlantic/North Sea shores, but stayed somehow neutral and even if it was invaded, they didn't have bad, bloody fights inside its territory and no armies on the Russian territory, like in Romania's case. So I wonder... what could have been done differently and could a better diplomacy/negotiation keep Romania neutral?

**Question: Was Romania such an important player in WWII that entering the would have been inevitable? Were Russia and Germany so dependent on Romania?**

*I base this theory by listening to what king Michael was saying about Antonescu (see video [here](https://youtu.be/cuu2L77l8J0?t=22m55s)) and considering some details from his biography.

Comment: is this a counterfactual?  Is this an example of the [doubt the existing narrative](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/1401) anti-pattern?

Comment: No armies on Russian territory?  Perhaps I don't understand your meaning.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace : I suppose he means that Denmark didn't send troops to fight in Russia on German side, while Romania did.

Comment: Generally, answers that are entirely personal speculation are strongly discouraged here, so we can't really do "What If"s, unless actual historians have written on that exact topic and an answer can factually report that.

Comment: ...However, what answers **can** do is talk about what their incentives for joining were, and what kind of headaches would have been caused to the other belligerents without Romania's participation (which would speak to why they might have been forced in against their will).

Comment: If the "What if" is what you really, really want though, there's always Worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about Denmark not sending troops to Stalingrad, for example. @T.E.D., it is true that it is a long debate. Though, I was expecting that there might be someone here who has studied this particular situation and found more reasons than the two described in the OP. There is always more details "behind the curtains" (e.g., religion, economics, blackmailing, etc.)

Comment: No, Denmark was not "somewhat neutral" and it did not "solve it diplomatically", **it had been invaded** and the recognized (by the Allies) government was at war with Germany since May 1940. Denmark simply could not send troops because there was no independent "Denmark" so there was no Danish Army to send. And nonetheless [6,000 volunteers were recruited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS_foreign_volunteers_and_conscripts#Denmark), but they fought under the German flag (which technically made them traitors).

Comment: I think T.E.D.'s suggestion for what historians *can* do is an excellent basis for editing and trying to reopen this question.

Comment: Done. Q: Was Romania such an important player in WWII that entering the would have been inevitable? Were Russia and Germany so dependent on Romania?

Comment: You should try to edit the question if you really need it opened. Antonescu came to power for a reason, replacing the king Carol II who wanted to stay neutral and exterminated the fascist Iron Guards.

Comment: Romania received the same guarantee from Britain and France in 1939 as did Poland. It was only after the French withdrew from the war that Romania became obviously isolated, and vulnerable to the predations of the USSR, Hungary, and Germany. Once Germany went to war with Britain she became dependent on Romania and/or the USSR for oil. That's the bottom line.

Answer (score 5):

Based in historical facts, we might say that Romania was not neutral by then.

Russia occupied Bessarabia and Bukovina from Romania early in the war. Hence, Romania neutrality was already violated. It was after those events that Romania entered in alliance with Germany.

Comment: That's also true. But so was Denmark, which solved it a bit more diplomatically, i.e., without bloody fights (see for example Erik Scavenius). They cooperated with the Nazis like the Romanians, but they were more mellow and saved lives. Can one blame Antonescu for this or is there something else behind these decisions? Could he have kept neutrality, even if Romania was invaded?

Comment: @Physther . My answer in worldbuilding mode: Romania would not be able to stay neutral. Because if we assume that they do not enter in the war in the axis side, they would have ended as Bulgaria. Bulgaria was forced by Russia to declare war to Germany at the end of the war, they had to send its army to liberate Yugoeslavia.

Comment: That makes sense. So the two pressures - Germany and Russia - would basically force it into the war in any circumstances or suffer great loses...

Comment: Not precisely the answer. Hungary had also taken part of Transylvania, and Bulgaria part of Dobrudja. These violations were made by (or in parallel to) the Ribbentrop-Molotov treaty (which was basically a short alliance of the future belligerents) in that case against the neutral Romania. Thus being neutral showed to be a losing policy, although a possible one as long as USSR and Germany were not at war with each other.

Comment: `Bulgaria was forced by Russia to declare war to Germany` - Romania ended worse than Bulgaria, its army having to fight the Germans in Hungary and Czechoslovakia after having been partially wiped out at Stalingrad. - But when Romania entered the war it had great incentive for that, namely the fact that most people thought Germany would win the war.

Comment: @Physther - Antonescu came in power against the previous policy which was precisely neutrality. Germany seemed victorious and joining them might have seemed a good political move - although incidentally criminal (considering what happened to the Jews and the Soviet populations) and suicidal (considering what happened at Stalingrad). - The way you formulate your question is indeed odd (`Could he have kept neutrality?`). He being Antonescu. The man is what it is because of what he did; asking that is like asking could he have been called differently.

Comment: @Physther - Antonescu came to power because Carol II fell, who fell because his policy of neutrality brought territorial losses (Ribbentrop-Molotov); those were possible because Hitler had beaten the French and the British. So, Antonescu came to power because of Hitler. Carol had persecuted the fascist Iron Guards, Antonescu brought them to power, let them massacre the Jews. Against his will? Maybe, but anticipating the Iasi massacre and the war crimes on the Eastern front - mostly his own doing. If Antonescu massacred the Iron Guards too is because he didn't need them. He needed Hitler.

Comment: @Physther - to put it differently: Antonescu came with a non-neutrality policy because the neutrality was disastrous for Romania up to then; the fact that he came to power is the very answer to the question: no, Romania could not have  remained neutral and independent under his rule, but it might have avoided invading USSR by being occupied before he came to power, and avoiding him taking power. But the army came to power and he became the leader because the army wanted to fight, only not Germany. (Denmark was occupied, by the way, so was Yugoslavia, where guerilla and civil war started.)

Comment: Thank you for the nice answers, @cipricus

Comment: @Physther - Not entering the war would have been impossible for Antonescu, not invading at least Bessarabia unimaginable, hence the inevitability of Romanian army entering war against USSR and its allies. But,it is an interesting question whether Romanians could have stopped advancing somewhere between Dniester and Stalingrad, possibly after taking Odessa.

Comment: @Physther - A factual question (one that wouldn't be closed) would be: was the Romanian army, as well as the others, Italian, Hungarian, under direct German command? were they  following directly Hitler's plan of attack or would have they been able to stop action based on their leaders decision? I guess they were theoretically independent, but the full participation had been negotiated in advance.

Comment: @Physther - Beside the geographical advance, there is also the problem of the level of involvement in numbers, as Romania's was [second only to Germany on Eastern front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romania_in_World_War_II#The_war_on_the_Eastern_Front). The question (closer to yours, but more factual) would be: **what factors have determined that high level of intervention (geographically and in numbers)?** - Romania had to compensate maybe its bad position after Ribbentrop-Mol., also it had the most to lose in case of USSR victory being more to the East.

Comment: @cipricus, I have opened a new topic. Thanks for the suggestions! https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/49778/was-romania-under-german-command-during-wwii

Comment: `we might say that Romania was not neutral by then`. Not true. It had been a WW1 ally of Russia, France and England. Neutral, it suffered the effects of the 1940  Ribbentrop-Molotov pact (along others, less severely than Poland and the Baltic states, more severely than Finland). Arguably the most severe loss was that of parts of Transylvania to Hungary (that territory was the main reason for Romanians taking part to WW1 and losing 350,000 people out of 7.8 million). It also lost land to Bulgaria. Attacking USSR meant taking land back from them, but not from Hungary etc.

Comment: Germany was in a way instrumental in the loses in favor of USSR.  But Romanians entered war on Germany's side because **(1)**  it seemed like betting on the winning horse (like in WW1, only the horse was different), **(2)** they had not much choice (neutrality proved disastrous, former allies had been knocked out, Romania was not an island, nor with  the back to the Polar circle, like Finland), **(3)** fascist and anti-soviet ideology became very popular especially after 1940.